# Windows authentication + Forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, ipad, authentication, iis

I'm using **forms authentication for one page** in my asp.net project. The forms authentication **works with windows credentials** (so it doesn't use a username/password db, it just checks against active directory)

Now other files in that project use windows authentication. I want the user to be able to access these files **without having to log in again** (I'm developing for IPad, which prompts the user for credentials when using windows authentication). Since the form authentication uses the users windows credentials, these are known to the server.

All I need now, is to authenticate the user via windows authentication **programmatically** (using the previously given credentials).

Comment: I think you need [Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx).  There are some serious limitations however.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your network credentials this way:

```
WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy();
myProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Environment.UserName,YOURPASS);
```

Comment: Could you explain this? What do I have to do with this WebProxy object now? According to MSDN it is used for the WebRequest class, which i don't use. The user opens the website by himself, so i dont do that programmatically. I only want to do the authentication programmatically.

Comment: oh my bad but in a way or another you will have to store passwords secured and link them to the logged on user, because you can't access windows password within the program explicitly.

Comment: Well storing them isn't the problem. The user submits the password via forms authentication anyways. But I'd like to know how to 'link' that with the windows authentication ;)